# Leaflet in R: ArcGIS Server custom CRS mismatch

Tags: coordinate-system, r, leaflet

I am trying to use tiles from the ArcGIS Server in Leaflet, but I can´t get the projection right. The tiles use a specific projection which I defined, but when I plot them on top of a base map it is totally off. What is wrong?

Code is as follows:

```
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.esri)


    epsg28992 <- leafletCRS(
      crsClass = "L.Proj.CRS"
      ,code = "EPSG:28992"
      ,proj4def = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.417,50.3319,465.552,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.8774,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs"
      ,origin=c(-285401.92,903401.92)
      ,resolutions = c(3251.206502413005,1625.6032512065026,812.8016256032513,406.40081280162565,203.20040640081282,101.60020320040641, 50.800101600203206,25.400050800101603,12.700025400050801,6.350012700025401,3.1750063500127004,1.5875031750063502,0.7937515875031751,0.39687579375158755,0.19843789687579377,0.09921894843789689,0.04960947421894844)
    )
    
    
    
    
    leaflet(options = leafletOptions(
      crs = epsg28992, minZoom = 0, maxZoom = 16)) %>%
      setView(5.092098, 52.093992, zoom = 4) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addEsriTiledMapLayer(url = "https://services.arcgisonline.nl/arcgis/rest/services/Basiskaarten/Open_Topo/MapServer",
                           group = "Open_Topo", options = tileOptions(opacity = .5,minZoom = 0, maxZoom = 16, tileSize = 256))
```

Comment: In Leaflet all layers must have the same CRS as is declared for map. Since standard layer added with the `addTiles()` is in Web Mercator, it cannot show correctly, since in Leaflet there is no automatic raster layer reprojection as in OpenLayers.

Comment: I see! Makes sense. Is there a way to reproject base layers like osm?

Comment: Unfortunately not.